# Can't find css and js after facebook login in codeigniter progect

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

My site is working fine before i added ssl, but after installed ssl the facebook login isnt work properly, After facebook login the css, js and images on the page is giving 500 error, path is fine for all of these, but still its showing "500 Internal Server Error" in firebug net.

Please help me out for the same.

Comment: A link to your site might be helpful, or shall we just guess?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dale https://www.complaintsofconsumer.com

Comment: The absolute first thing you always do on an internal _server_ error, is you go check the relevant server log files to find out more about what caused it.

Comment: Hi. @CBroe I have checked that too, There is nothing in server log file.

Comment: Then make sure that you have your PHP configured to properly log errors.

Comment: Make sure you have set your base url in config.php if your url has ip address showing in it links may not work.

Comment: In my config file the base url is https://www.complaintsofconsumer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site and seems like you have not defined default controller in `routes.php`.

Please add default controller in `application/config/routes.php` file and check.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Please check and let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Hi my default controller is "home" only.

Comment: Sure.. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p57byo50tjmrqx5/.htaccess?dl=0 please check on dropbox